# Como utilizar uma variável dentro de outra função?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando demonstrar um valor ao clicar em um botão. Para isso eu preciso de ir buscar o valor a uma variável já criada, mas que se encontra em outra função.
Este é o meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//visualizar dados da linha da tabela ao carregar no botão
var tabela = document.getElementById("minhaTabela");
var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
  var linha = linhas[i];
  linha.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //Adicionar ao atual
    selLinha(this, false); //Selecione apenas um
    //selLinha(this, true); //Selecione quantos quiser
  });
}


function selLinha(linha, multiplos){
  if(!multiplos){
    var linhas = linha.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++){
      var linha_ = linhas[i];
      linha_.classList.remove("selecionado");    
    }
  }
  linha.classList.toggle("selecionado");
}

/**
Exemplo de como capturar os dados
**/
var btnVisualizar = document.getElementById("visualizarDados");

btnVisualizar.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var selecionados = tabela.getElementsByClassName("selecionado");
  //Verificar se eestá selecionado
  if(selecionados.length < 1){
    window.alert("Selecione pelo menos uma linha");
    return false;
  }
  
  var dados = "";

  for(var i = 0; i < selecionados.length; i++){
    var selecionado = selecionados[i];
    selecionado = selecionado.getElementsByTagName("td");
    dados += " - ID: " + selecionado[0].innerHTML +
            "\n"+ " - Designação: " + selecionado[1].innerHTML +
            "\n"+ " - Morada: " + selecionado[2].innerHTML +
            "\n"+ " - Estado: " + selecionado[4].innerHTML +
            "\n"+ " - Criado a: " + selecionado[5].innerHTML +
            "\n"+ " - Foto: " + selecionado[6].innerHTML + "\n";
  }
  
  window.alert(dados);
  return dados;
});

//botão resolvido
function cResolvido(){
   //var id = document.getElementById("btnResolvido").value;
  window.alert("Resolvido");
}
```

O meu objetivo é mostrar a variável `dados` na função `cResolvido`.
Alguém me consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar o `var dados = ''` fora da função assim ela se torna uma variável global que tem escopo global : todos os scripts e funções em uma página da web podem acessá-la.
E também mesmo estando dentro ou fora da função, aonde você preferir colocar, você atribui um valor a variável `dados` mas não a declara (declarações: `var` `let` `const`) ficando apenas `dados = ''` *(independente de onde esteja)*

Se você atribuir um valor a uma variável que não foi declarada, ela se tornará automaticamente uma variável **GLOBAL** e assim todos os scripts e funções em uma página da web podem acessá-la .

***LEMBRANDO CUIDADO AO FAZER ISSO POIS NENHUMA OUTRA VARIÁVEL PODE OBTER O NOME DE UMA VARIÁVEL GLOBAL, NO CASO QUE FALEI AÍ A VARIÁVEL*** `dados` ***E ALGUNS EXEMPLOS DO SEU CASO SÃO AS VARIÁVEIS*** `linhas` e `btnVisualizar` e `tabela` ***QUE VOCÊ DENOMINOU FORA DE FUNÇÕES.***

Em vez de

```js
var btnVisualizar = document.getElementById("visualizarDados");

btnVisualizar.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var selecionados = tabela.getElementsByClassName("selecionado");
  //Verificar se eestá selecionado
  if(selecionados.length < 1){
    window.alert("Selecione pelo menos uma linha");
    return false;
  }
  
  **var dados = "";**

 (...)
```

Você pode fazer :

Fora de Funções:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
//visualizar dados da linha da tabela ao carregar no botão
var tabela = document.getElementById("minhaTabela");
var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var dados = ''


(...)// funções e coisas
```

Em qualquer lugar sem declarar a variável:
(nesse exemplo no mesmo lugar que você colocou a sua `var dados`)

**Exemplo de teste** (Execute ele)

```js
  var btnVisualizar = document.getElementById('visualizarDados')
    btnVisualizar.addEventListener("click", function(){

     dados = "";
     dados += 'TESTE'
     alert(dados)
     setTimeout(cResolvido,3000)//chamar função cResolvido depois de 3seg
     })
       //vou fechar a função para fazer o teste (buscar ele em outra função)
     function cResolvido() {
     alert(`cResolvido função pegar dados, dados é ${dados}`)
     }
```

```html
<div id="visualizarDados">
    <p>Visualizar dados - teste (CLICK-ME)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: está a funcionar, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2):

Bom, as duas formas mais simples são:

**1. Chamar, de dentro do escopo original da variável, a função que você quer passando a
variável pra dentro como argumento**:

Chamar `[nomeDaFunçãoQueRecebeAVariável](dados)` de dentro da função `[nomeDaFunçãoOriginal]()`.

**2. Retornando a variável ao escopo global no final da função:**

Declarar:

```
[nomeDaFunçãoOriginal](){
   // ...
   dados = "";
   // ...
   return { dados };
 }
```

Então, pra acessar esse valor de dentro de outra função, você chama
com:

```
[nomeDaFunçãoOriginal]().dados;
```

(ou insere esse caminho dentro de uma variável local, pra facilitar a
escrita do resto do código, ficar mais organizado)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa que a variável `dados` seja uma variável global. Como você definiu a variável dentro de uma função, ela só vai funcionar dentro dessa função.

1. **O que é o escopo de uma variável?**

> Quando nos referimos a escopo de variável estamos se referindo a qual
> local de nosso código uma determinada variável pode ser acessada. No
> JavaScript existem somente dois tipos de escopos, que são eles, escopo
> global e local.

2. **Declarando variáveis no escopo global**

> Uma variável global é definida quando declaramos uma variável fora de
> qualquer função, assim ela torna acessível a qualquer parte da nossa
> aplicação ou site, podendo ser lida e alterada.

Fonte e exemplos [aqui](https://medium.com/weyes/entendendo-o-uso-de-escopo-no-javascript-3669172ca5ba).

Comment: Boa tarde, já corrigi como o senhor disse, mas eu faço return do valor da variavel, e quando faço o window.alert(dados), dados é null. como faço para atribuir o valor a dados.